# Wires do not connect in Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I've been trying to use relative coordinates to make my drawings more precise but it seems I don't know how the command `\node` works since I've been having this problem while connecting a circuit element to another:

[image]

I'm trying to eliminate the blank between the two wires.

This is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz} %Circuit Schematics/Diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
            \path (0,0) coordinate (C);
            % Comparatore
            \path (C) + (0,-1) + (1,0) coordinate (com) node[above]{};
            \path (com) + (1.5,-1) node[op amp] (comp) {};
            % Collegamenti Comparatore
            \node (G1) at ([shift=({-1.3cm,0cm})]comp.-) {};
            \draw (G1) -- (comp.-);
            \node (G2) at ([shift=({-1.3cm,0cm})]comp.+) {};
            \draw (G2) -- (comp.+);
            \draw (C) -- (G1); % Collegamento Rettificatore - Comparatore
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Sorry. I went lost in your code, so I write new one, which reproduce desired result. I preserve `coordinate (C)` regardless that it is not needed for drawing this picture.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz} %Circuit Schematics/Diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
            % Collegamenti Comparatore
\node   (comp)  [op amp, right, anchor=-] {};
\draw   (comp.-)  -- ++ (-1,0) coordinate (C)
                  -- ++ ( 0,1)
        (comp.+)  -- (C |- comp.+)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My sincere compliments for the sinthetic code :-)

Answer (score 13):

Although the [answer by Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498856/38080) is correct, the problem in your code (apart a bit of strange path building) is this line:

```
\node (G1) at ([shift=({-1.3cm,0cm})]comp.-) {};
```

and you can see it if you substitute your code with:

```
 \node [draw=red](G1) at ([shift=({-1.3cm,0cm})]comp.-) {};
```

which gives:

[image: detail of node G1]

Nodes have a minimum size, and when they are connected the connection goes to the "neareast" border. This is why in this case you should use `\coordinate`, which have no size.

If you insist on nodes, you should then connect to the `center` anchor:

```
 \draw (G1.center) -- (comp.-);
 \draw (C) -- (G1.center); % Collegamento Rettificatore - Comparatore
```

[image: connecting to center anchor]

although this is still sub-optimal:

[image: bad connection]

and this is why the accepted solution is better.

Just as an additional bonus, you can use my `\coord()` macro to show where your path is going...

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz} %Circuit Schematics/Diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning}
\def\coord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]45:#1}](#1){}}
% \def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
            \path (0,0) \coord (C);
            % Comparatore
            \path (C) + (0,-1) \coord(1) + (1,0) \coord (com) node[above]{};
            \path (com) + (1.5,-1) \coord(3) node[op amp] (comp) {};
            % Collegamenti Comparatore
            \node [draw=red](G1) at ([shift=({-1.3cm,0cm})]comp.-) {};
            \path (G1) \coord(g1 center) (comp.-) \coord(-) (G1.north) \coord(g1 north);
            \draw (G1) -- (comp.-);
            \node (G2) at ([shift=({-1.3cm,0cm})]comp.+) {};
            \draw (G2) -- (comp.+);
            \path (G2) \coord(g2 center) (comp.+) \coord(+);
            \draw (C) -- (G1); % Collegamento Rettificatore - Comparatore
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: showing coordinates]

Comment: Thank you! Your macro looks extremely useful for identifying the position of the various anchors of components, which I've been having trouble with. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 but I do not see why you are so critical with your answer. The unfortunate feature will be gone immediately if you use `\draw (C) -- (G1.center) -- (comp.-);` or `\draw (C) |- (comp.-);` or `\draw (comp.-) -| ++(-1,1);`. The second and third options do not even require the center anchor. (Similarly Zarko's answer could be made "more concise" using `\draw   (comp.-)  -| ++ (-1,1) coordinate (C)        (comp.+)  -- (C |- comp.+);` or  `\draw   (comp.-)  -| ++ (-1,1)        (comp.+)  --++(-1,0);`.)