# CircuiTikz bug - unwanted point shift

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, bugs

I have been working with CircuiTikz recently and I have encountered an unwanted feature. Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}% dessin

\usepackage[straightvoltages, siunitx]{circuitikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}

\coordinate (A) at (10,0);
\coordinate (B) at (12,0);
\coordinate (C) at (14,0);
\coordinate (D) at (16,0);
\coordinate (E) at (18,0);
\coordinate (F) at (12,1);

\draw (A) -- (B) ;
\node[] at (B) {O};
\draw (F) to (B) [european resistor=R,v<=$u_{R}$] 
    to (C) [L=$L$,v<=$u_{L}$]
    to (D) [V]
    to (E);
    \node[] at (B) {0};
    
\end{circuitikz}


\end{document}
```

It gives :

[image: Shited B]

Where you can see that the point B seems to have shifted slightly to the right on its own accord.

And if you change the line `to (D) [V]` to `%to (D) [V]` it gives :

[image]

Where there is no shift.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a wrong syntax. It is not `(F) to (B) [european resistor=R,v<=$u_{R}$]` , but `(F) to[european resistor=R,v<=$u_{R}$] (B)`. You are applying the inner options of the R, L, V nodes to the whole path.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the lines to : \draw (F) to (B) 
     to[european resistor=R,v<=$u_{R}$] (C) 
        to[L=$L$,v<=$u_{L}$] (D) 
        to[V] (E);
        \node[] at (B) {0};
and it works now

Comment: Apart from the wrong syntax, be careful with the fact that Ti*k*Z nodes have finite size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498852/wires-do-not-connect-in-circuitikz